# My jQuery code not working in local system but working in jsFiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The following code works fine at JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/z5ey2/ but not working in local. Code follows.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
            <title>Untitled Document</title>
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $( "#OVERALL_VALUE" ).click(function() {
                    $( "#ajaxload_more3" ).show("slow");
                    $("#ajaxload_more3").delay(6000).fadeOut("slow");
                });
                $( "#PRICE" ).click(function() {
                    $( "#ajaxload_more3" ).show("slow");
                    $("#ajaxload_more3").delay(6000).fadeOut("slow");
                });
                $( "#QUALITY" ).click(function() {
                    $( "#ajaxload_more3" ).show("slow");
                    $("#ajaxload_more3").delay(6000).fadeOut("slow");
                });
                $( "#list" ).click(function() {
                    $( "#ajaxload_more3" ).show("slow");
                    $("#ajaxload_more3").delay(6000).fadeOut("slow");
                });
                $( "#grid" ).click(function() {
                    $( "#ajaxload_more3" ).show("slow");
                    $("#ajaxload_more3").delay(6000).fadeOut("slow");
                });
                $( "#map" ).click(function() {
                    $( "#ajaxload_more3" ).show("slow");
                    $("#ajaxload_more3").delay(6000).fadeOut("slow");
                });
            </script>
        </head>

        <body>
            <ul class="tabset">
                <li><a id="OVERALL_VALUE" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="setTopDeals('OVERALL_VALUE')" class="topdeal">Top Deals</a></li>
                <li><a id="PRICE" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="setTopDeals('PRICE')" class="price">Price</a></li>
                <li><a id="QUALITY" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="setTopDeals('QUALITY')" class="quality">Star Rating</a></li>
                <li><a id="list" href="javascript:void(0)" class="list">List View</a></li>
                <li><a id="grid" href="javascript:void(0)" class="gallery">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a id="map" href="javascript:void(0)" class="map">Map View</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a id="ajaxload_more3" style="display:none; width:200px; height:80px; border:1px solid #000; opacity:0.8; border-radius:10px; padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:25px; position:fixed; top:50%; left:50%; z-index:1000; text-align:center; background-color:#997CE6;"><table align="center"><tr height="50"><td><img src="images/ajaxload.gif" height="50" width="50" /></td></tr><tr height="35"><td><span style="font-size:20px; color:#FFF;">Loading</span></td></tr></table></a>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: And please (!), [read the jQuery tutorial](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/). It clearly states that you should put your code inside the `$(document).ready(...)` callback: *"To run code as soon as the document is ready to be manipulated, jQuery has a statement known as the ready event."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

missing http in your .js file..

Comment: Why does adding https solve the problem? Why does it not work without it?

Comment: The missing protocol is only a problem when the document is loaded from local filesystem. When the protocol  has been ommited the protocol will be inherited from the document. On local filesystem it will be `file:` , so the path will be translated to `file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js` (where the file can't be found). Conclusion: you may ommit the protocol, but only when you run the page on a webserver.

Answer (score 0):

Your saying before giving `https:` its not worked, but it worked after giving protocol.Missing protocol should not be a problem, once check [this](http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/#protocolless).

You might have changed other then protocol in your code, so it worked for you. Its better practice to check JavaScritp console for errors, instead of blindly coding.

**Edit:**

From Felix Kling comment, if your loading your document from file system you must give protocol , if your loading your document from webserver then no need to give protocol. Thanks Felix for pointing this note.

Comment: Since the OP mentions that it's not working on his file system, I assume that he really is loading the HTML document as `file://`. In that case, protocol-less CDN links won't work, because `file://` will be used as protocol.